# layout desing 3.2 inch screen android

Tags: android, android-layout

when I create a layout I add one imageview and then two buttons. 
It's look ok in 5 inch screen, but in 3.2 inch the buttons in bottom not shows correctly. A half of button is out of screen.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
    style="@style/TextPrincipal"
    android:text="@string/ferits_activity"/>
<View android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:background="#8a9597"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:layout_centerVertical ="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:src="@drawable/esquerra"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/FeritsImatge"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="240dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ferits_activity"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/esta_ferida"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40.0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="40.0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    style="@style/AppTheme">
    <Button android:id="@+id/BotoSiFerits"
        android:background="#ffabd128"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
        android:text="@string/resposta_si"
        android:textColor="@color/blanc"
        style="@style/AppTheme"
        android:onClick="passarMoure"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/BotoNoFerits"
        android:background="#ffabd128"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
        android:text="@string/resposta_no"
        android:layout_below="@id/BotoSiFerits"
        android:textColor="@color/blanc"
        style="@style/AppTheme"
        android:onClick="passarEsperar" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's your question? If you want to keep the same layout, you could wrap it all in a ScrollView and smaller devices could just scroll to display the rest...?

Comment: I try the ScrollView solution and works perfect. Lot of thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have too much content to fit on the screen, you have two general options:

1. Adapt the size of your content or the layout of your content for smaller screens so that everything can fit on the screen
2. Use a `ScrollView` so that the user can scroll your content if they have a smaller screen.

I recommend going with option 2, as it will provide a more consistent experience between devices.

Your layout should end up looking something like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Your existing LinearLayout with the height set to wrap_content -->

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Work perfect, I use the Scrollview to smaller screen.